# Surface-to-volume scaling

Tags: differential-geometry, fractals

For simple bodies, such as cube or sphere, the surface scales with the volume as
$$
S=\alpha V^\beta,$$
Where
$$
\beta=\frac{2}{3},
$$
And $\alpha$ is of the order of unity.

While this is intuitively obvious for "simple" non-regular shapes, it clearly breaks for fractal surfaces. I am therefore looking for clear mathematical statements:

- When the scaling above is applicable?
- What is the range of variation of factor $\alpha$?

**Remark:** this question is inspired by [my answer to the infamous "chicken surface problem"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623495/247642), which provoked [such heated debates](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13460/247642).

**Update**
To generalize a bit: in $n$ dimensions we expect for a closed surface/volume:
$$
V\propto R^n, \\
S\propto R^{n-1},
$$
where $R$ is the length scale. When is this not true?

Comment: That the naive scaling law is not obeyed is essentially the *definition* of a fractal, so you are not going to get a much more precise statement than one that affirms the fractal structure.

Comment: +1 I really like this question, but I'm also voting to close it as I think it would be far more suited to [math.se]. I think it would be a good idea to migrate it there.

Comment: @Philip it is indeed mathematical in essence, but I expect physicists to have a better understanding of scaling and the practical side of the differential geometry.